# Connect To amazon instance on a port from android app

Tags: java, android, http

I have an application running on port xxxx on my amazon instance with ip aa.aaa.a.aaa
Currently i can connect via telnet using

```
telnet aa.aaa.a.aaa xxxx
```

It's a chat application which receives messages from any connected clients and broadcasts the message to all other clients and so far it works well with telnet

I want to know how i can connect to this application from within an android application.
This is what i have tried so far in android

```
public String connect () {
        Scanner scan;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://54.214.9.156:8189");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                scan = new Scanner(in);

                boolean done = false;
                while(!done){
                    if (scan.hasNextLine()){
                        String line = scan.nextLine();
                        if (line.trim().equals("BYE")) done=true;
                        return line;
                    }
                }

            }finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return "";
    }
```

Doesn't work though, and my debugger tells me nothing.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thanks
NB: The chat application is written with java using server sockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have this line in your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And also if you are making your network request on the main thread you'll need to use AsyncTask(preferred) or Thread/Handler to move your network operations to a background thread. In later versions of the Android system it throws an exception if you try to do network calls on the main thread.